# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using fscanf to read into a pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, argv, coredump

I'm trying to use fscanf to read and print every character on the screen, but I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) when I run the program. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int *a ;
    FILE *input;

    if (argc>=2) {
        input= fopen(argv[1],"r");

        if (input!=NULL) {
            while (feof(input)==0) {
                fscanf(input,"%d\n",a);
                printf("%d\n",*a);
            }
            fclose(input);
        } else {
            printf("Error!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I provide the file as an argument, like this:

```
./myprog input.txt
```

The file `input.txt` contains this:

```
23
47
55
70
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable `a` is not initialized to point to a valid memory address.

Therefore, it is most likely pointing to an invalid memory address.

**Here is one way to fix it:**

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
...
free(a); // when done using it
```

**Here is another way to fix it:**

```
int b;
int *a = &b;
```

But I suggest that you follow the steps below in order to make it simpler and cleaner...

---

**Change this:**

```
int *a;
```

**To this:**

```
int a;
```

**And this:**

```
fscanf(input,"%d\n",a);
```

**To this:**

```
fscanf(input,"%d\n",&a);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
int *a;
```

then `a` is a *pointer*, but currently it does not point anywhere.

You have to make it point to valid storage for an `int`, before you supply it to `fscanf`.

For example, inside `main()`:

```
int b;
a = &b;
fscanf(input,"%d\n",a);
```

Also, your loop is wrong. It is almost always an error to use `feof` (let alone, as a loop condition). Instead, you should test the actual read operation. In your case:

```
while ( 1 == fscanf(input,"%d\n",a) )
{
     printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: The first sentence comment is false. A variable declared with `int *a;` is initialized to null pointer if it is a **static** variable, for example a variable defined in the global scope of the module (that is, outside of any function). In the case discussed here, however, the variable is declared inside the `main()` function, so it is an automatic variable, and it needn't be initialized. Consequently it points ANYWHERE, most probably into some non-existing or at least non-accessible area of memory, thus reading into an area pointed causes segmentation exception.

Comment: sorry, I must have misread OP's code, I thought `int *a;` was before `main()`.